# Alternative to bitwise operation

Tags: mysql, logic

Scenario : 
 I have say 4 check boxes and users can select those checkboxes in any combination(they also have the power to not select even a single check box). I have to store these 4 options to a single column. I think the best option is to store using binary representation

```
option1 has the constant value 1 
option2 has the constant value 2
option3 has the constant value 4
option4 has the constant value 8
```

So if the customer selects option2 and option4, then the value that is stored in the DB will be 2 + 8 ie: 10, if customer selects option1, option4 and option8 the value will be 1 + 4 + 8 which is 13.

Also when I query from mysql I can use

```
Select * from option_table where (option & 4)=4;
```

if I want to retrieve rows where option3 is selected.

But for some reason I cannot use this approach, or just say I need to know what's the next best option to store these multiple values in a single column ?

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column is **never** the right solution.

"But for some reason I cannot use this approach"

Go on, gives us a clue why not.

Comment: That's a strange set of constraints you are under. You *have* to use one column, but *cannot* use a bit mask. Why?

Comment: @symcbean: performance requirements often overwrite those kind of rules.

Comment: Define "cannot use this approach" - Do you mean that using bitmasks is not allowed, or that trying this is failing for you?

Comment: Because the framework which I use doesnt support bitwise operation.

Comment: @yi_H: and how exactly would you create an index to select specific items from a bitfield? Or do you think that indexes don't help performance?

Comment: I just reflected on your comment which stated that "Storing multiple values in a single column is *never* the right solution", which is obviously *wrong*. There are dozens of use cases where you *don't* have to search for the separate values (an example would be a lot of setting bits for the user on a portal: adjust daylight saving, show time with 24h or am/pm, send email on private message, etcetc.. you never have to search for these fields)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative could be to multiply prime numbers.  To select, you would select columns where the modulus of the prime number into the value of the column is 0.

Example:

Value 1: 2
Value 2: 3
Value 3: 5
Value 4: 7

Value 2 & 3 would be 3*5 = 15
Values 1, 2, 3, 4 would be 2*3*5*7 = 210

To get the rows where value 1 is on, select where `value % 2 == 0`

Comment: If you can't use bit's and you should be able to, `select 1 from dual where 4 & 4 = 4;` works just fine, but if you can't use bits, this is a pretty solid option.

Comment: Yes this is a good one. But I would wait some more time to see if there are any other way this can be done. Thanks evan .

Answer (score 1):

You can always use this approach as long the number of bits is less equal than the bit length of the type for that column. If there are more bits to store you can use multiple columns(fields).

You can also use [Bit Fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-values.html).