# Bitwise operation alternative in Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I need to do a bitwise "and" in a cypher query. It seems that cypher does not support bitwise operations. Any suggestions for alternatives?
This is what I want to detect ...
For example 268 is (2^8 + 2^3 + 2^2) and as you can see 2^3 = 8 is a part of my original number. So if I use bitwise AND it will be (100001100) & (1000) = 1000 so this way I can detect if 8 is a part of 268 or not.
How can I do this without bitwise support? any suggestions? I need to do this in cypher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dave. I tried your solutions and they all worked. They were a good hint for me to find another approach. This is how I solved it. I used String comparison.

```
 with '100001100' as number , '100000000' as sub_number
 with number,sub_number,range(length (number)-1,length (number)-length(sub_number),-1) as tail,length (number)-length(sub_number) as difference
 unwind tail as i
 with i,sub_number,number, i - length (number) + length (sub_number) as sub_number_position
 with sub_number_position, (split(number,''))[i-1] as bit_mask , (split(sub_number,''))[sub_number_position] as sub_bit 
 with collect(toInt(bit_mask) * toInt(sub_bit)) as result

return result
```

Obviously the number and sub_number can have different values.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to perform this type of test using cypher would be to convert your decimal values to collections of the decimals that represent the bits that are set.

```
// convert the binary number to a collection of decimal parts
// create an index the size of the number to convert
// create a collection of decimals that correspond to the bit locations
with '100001100' as number
, [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096] as decimals
with number
, range(length(number)-1,0,-1) as index
, decimals[0..length(number)] as decimals

// map the bits to decimal equivalents
unwind index as i
with number, i, (split(number,''))[i] as binary_placeholder, decimals[-i-1] as decimal_placeholder

// multiply the decimal value by the bits that are set
with collect(decimal_placeholder * toInt(binary_placeholder)) as decimal_placeholders

// filter out the zero values from the collection
with filter(d in decimal_placeholders where d > 0) as decimal_placeholders
return decimal_placeholders
```

Here is a sample of what this returns.

[image]

Then when you want to test whether the number is in the decimal, you can just test the actual decimal for presence in the collection.

```
with [4, 8, 256] as decimal_placeholders
, 8 as decimal_to_test
return 
  case 
    when decimal_to_test in decimal_placeholders then
      toString(decimal_to_test) + ' value bit is set'
    else
      toString(decimal_to_test) + ' value bit is NOT set'
    end as bit_set_test
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if one had APOC available they could use `apoc.bitwise.op` which is a wrapper around the java bitwise operations.

```
RETURN apoc.bitwise.op(268, "&",8 ) AS `268_AND_8`
```

Which yields the following result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to do the operation in cypher probably a better solution would be to implement something like @evan's SO solution [Alternative to bitwise operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581865/alternative-to-bitwise-operation) using cypher.

You could start by converting your data using cypher that looks something like this...

```
// convert binary to a product of prime numbers
// start with the number to conver an a collection of primes
with '100001100' as number
, [2,3,5,7,13,17,19,23,29,31,37] as primes

// create an index based on the size of the binary number to convert
// take a slice of the prime array that is the size of the number to convert
with number
, range(length(number)-1,0,-1) as index
, primes[0..length(number)] as primes, decimals[0..length(number)] as decimals

// iterate over the index and match the prime number to the bits in the number to convert
unwind index as i
with (split(number,''))[i] as binary_place_holder, primes[-i-1] as prime_place_holder, decimals[-i-1] as decimal_place_holder

// collect the primes that are set by multiplying by the set bits
with collect(toInt(binary_place_holder) * prime_place_holder) as prime_placeholders

// filter out the zero bits
with filter(p in prime_placeholders where p > 0) as prime_placeholders

// return a product of primes of the set bits
return prime_placeholders, reduce(pp = 1, p in prime_placeholders | pp * p) as prime_product
```

Sample of the output of the above query. The query could be adapted to update attributes with the prime product.

[image]

Here is a screen cap of how the conversion breaks down

[image]

Then when you want to use it you could use the modulus of the prime number in the location of the bit you want to test.

```
// test if the fourth bit is set in the decimal 268
// 268 is the equivalent of a prime product of 1015
// a modulus 7 == 0 will indicate the bit is set
with 1015 as prime_product
, [2,3,5,7,13,17,19,23,29,31,37] as primes
, 4 as bit_to_test
with bit_to_test
, prime_product
, primes[bit_to_test-1] as prime
, prime_product % primes[bit_to_test-1] as mod_remains
with 
  case when mod_remains = 0 then
    'bit ' + toString(bit_to_test) + ' set'
  else
    'bit ' + toString(bit_to_test) + ' NOT set'
  end as bit_set
return bit_set
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost certainly defeats the purpose of choosing a bitwise operation in the first place but if you absolutely needed to **AND** the two binary numbers in cypher you could do something like this with collections.

```
with split('100001100', '') as bin_term_1
, split('000001000', '') as bin_term_2
, toString(1) as one
with bin_term_1, bin_term_2, one, range(0,size(bin_term_1)-1,1) as index
unwind index as i
with i, bin_term_1, bin_term_2, one,
case 
  when (bin_term_1[i] = one) and (bin_term_2[i] = one) then
    1
  else
    0
  end as r
return collect(r) as AND
```